# How do I find an email I "accidently" archived in gmail (or is there a "recent activity" page in gmail)

Tags: gmail, gmail-archive

I tend to use keyboard shortcuts a lot in gmail. Sometimes, when the browser is slow in loading, I can press some keyboard shortcuts without getting the response in time. Recently, I ended up doing something (I know quite know what) and I noticed the number of emails in my inbox went from 12 to 9. I must have archived them by mistake.

How do I find those archived emails? I know I can search for emails, but the problem is that I don't remember what those emails were -- they were old and they were lying around in my mailbox.

Is there an "activity page" for gmail that can tell what actions I have taken: like archived this message, composed this message, deleted this another message, search for this query etc? Or some other way to find what I did in the last few minutes of a gmail session?

Answer (score 3):

first reply here :)

Sadly, nothing of what you have mentioned exists in Gmail, only powerful search engine.
If an email hasn't a label and it isn't in Inbox (that's a special label), then the email is in the "All mail" label.

Sorry for that.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I hope something else exists, but I think you are right. When you say "first reply", do you mean on Stack Exchange as a whole? Welcome! :-)

Comment: Yep, StackExchange newbie (but I've lurked for years) and have some answers on StackOverflow (not so much, but more than one)